# How to extract all elements of a specific property in a list?

Tags: java, collections

how can I best get all "name" string elements of the following structure:

```
class Foo {
    List<Bar> bars;
}

class Bar {
    private String name;
    private int age;
}
```

My approach would be:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

for (Bar bar : foo.getBars()) {
    names.add(bar.getName());
}
```

This might work, but isn't there something in java.`Collections` where I just can write like this:
`Collections.getAll(foo.getBars(), "name");`?

Comment: Just wait for Java 8 ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Java 8:

```
List<String> names =        
    foo.getBars().stream().map(Bar::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) and change getBars() to return a MutableList or something similar, you can write:

```
MutableList<String> names = foo.getBars().collect(new Function<Bar, String>()
{
    public String valueOf(Bar bar)
    {
        return bar.getName();
    }
});
```

If you extract the function as a constant on Bar, it shortens to:

```
MutableList<String> names = foo.getBars().collect(Bar.TO_NAME);
```

With Java 8 lambdas, you don't need the Function at all.

```
MutableList<String> names = foo.getBars().collect(Bar::getName);
```

If you can't change the return type of getBars(), you can wrap it in a ListAdapter.

```
MutableList<String> names = ListAdapter.adapt(foo.getBars()).collect(Bar.TO_NAME);
```

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse collections.

Comment: find two difference with answer by Guava Collections :)

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat provides Google guava

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList(Collections2.transform(foo.getBars(), new Function<Bar,String>() {
    String apply(Bar bar) {
        return bar.getName()
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, but type-safe and don't hide a logic

Answer (score -1):

Is there any reason why you couldn't use the MultiMap supplied by Googles collection framework?

[MultiMap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

This will allow a map with multiple key values.

So you could have a duplicate key (unlike say a hashmap) and return all the values for that key

Then just call get on the associated Map, which would be the same implementation as your expected example of "getAll"

> get
>
> Collection get(@Nullable
>                     K key) Returns a collection view of all values associated with a key. If no mappings in the multimap have the
>   provided key, an empty collection is returned. Changes to the returned
>   collection will update the underlying multimap, and vice versa.
>
> Parameters: key - key to search for in multimap Returns: the
>   collection of values that the key maps to